# Car won't crank

Tags: starter, no-crank-no-start, solenoid

Just fixed dead fuel pump. was working for a day and now car won't start again. No cranking sound, No repeated clicks. One small click when key is turned but unable to locate. Battery at 12.6V, headlights don't dim when key turned, current from solenoid small terminal to solenoid body and starter body. Yet to bench test starter. All fuses and relays have been checked. Any ideas? Do I need to bench test starter?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Bench testing the starter sounds like a good start (pun intended :o) ... It sounds like there's an issue with the solenoid. You might try rapping on it with a hammer before you take it off and see if it helps or not.

Comment: Tested battery? As in under load?

Comment: @SolarMike The fact that it remains at 12.6V tells that battery is not the problem.